# How to exit or close an UWP C++ app programmatically?

Tags: c++, xaml, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

I want to add "Exit" button in my app.
If I write something like this:

```
void LibraryUWP::MainPage::ExitEvent(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    Application::Exit;
}
```

I have an error:

> 1>...\mainpage.xaml.cpp(32): error C3867: 'Windows::UI::Xaml::Application::Exit': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

If I run

```
void LibraryUWP::MainPage::ExitEvent(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    Application::Exit();
}
```

I have:

> 1>...\mainpage.xaml.cpp(32): error C2352: 'Windows::UI::Xaml::Application::Exit': illegal call of non-static member function

And if I run this:

```
void LibraryUWP::MainPage::ExitEvent(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    Application::Current::Exit();
}
```

I have an error:

> 1>...\mainpage.xaml.cpp(32): error C2039: 'Exit': is not a member of 'Windows::UI::Xaml::Application::Current'
>   1>...\mainpage.xaml.cpp(32): error C3861: 'Exit': identifier not found

I understand, that first & second variant cannot work. But what about the third? Or something else?

MS Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.
For Windows 10.10240 platform

P.S. If I run third variant without last bracers, I have the same error, that tells me, that we have no such method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
void MyApp::MainPage::Button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    Application::Current->Exit();
}
```

Thanks,

Stefan Wick - Windows Developer Platform

Answer (score 0):

If your app only has one window, you can exit app like this:

```
void UWPcpp::MainPage::Button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    ApplicationView::GetForCurrentView()->TryConsolidateAsync();
}
```

This suspends your app instead of abruptly exiting it, also this is the only way when you relaunch your app it will have the same size and location as previous.